# Material table with sticky header and responsive columns

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

Is there a way I can have a material table with a sticky header and the columns responsive? I found this example on material documentation: https://stackblitz.com/angular/paddnlmnavx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-complex-flex-example.css

My issue here is that the header width is fixed, calculated using the cell's width:

```
min-width: 1920px; /* 24 columns, 80px each */
```

If I want to make the columns responsive then I will have a dynamic width for the columns and if I remove the min-width from the header, the header row will have a width of 100% and will not contain all the header cells.

Comment: What exactly do you need??

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is with `@media query`. You can change the `min-width` based on screen size and you will have responsive columns.

You can do it like this:

```
.mat-header-row,
.mat-footer-row,
.mat-row {
  min-width: 1920px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .mat-header-row,
  .mat-footer-row,
  .mat-row {
    min-width: 2500px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .mat-header-row,
  .mat-footer-row,
  .mat-row {
    min-width: 3000px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .mat-header-row,
  .mat-footer-row,
  .mat-row {
    min-width: 4000px;
  }
}
```

Here is the updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k6repx-qpnjoa?file=src/app/table-sticky-complex-flex-example.css

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code structure to make angular material table header as sticky.

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="headerdata" sticky></tr>
```

Adding `sticky` keyword  to the `<tr mat-header-row>` tag.  And this change will work in **angular 6.2.3+** version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true">
```

You can find more details on [this page](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sticky-rows-and-columns)